# Table join using the Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I'm trying to figure out the Django ORM and I'm getting a little confused on the equivalent of a table join.

Assume I have the three models below, abbreviated for readability. "User" is the out-of-the-box Django user model, "AppUser" is a corresponding model for storing additional profile info like zip code, and "Group" is a collection of users (note that this group has nothing to do with authentication groups). Each AppUser has a one-to-one relationship with each User. Similarly, each AppUser also points to the Group of which that user is member (which could be None).

My task: given a group_id, generate a list of all the member emails.

I know that I can "traverse backward one-level" from Group to AppUser using `.appuser_set.all()` but I don't know how to go further to fetch the related User and its email without iterating through and doing it in a very DB heavy way like this:

```
appUser = AppUser.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
group = appUser.group
appUsers = group.appuser_set.all()
emails = []
for x in appUsers:
    emails.append(x.user.email)
```

Alternatively I could write a raw SQL join to do it but suspect the Django ORM is capable. 
What's the proper and most efficient way to do this?

Models:

```
class User(Model):
    id = IntegerField()
    username = CharField()
    email = CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "auth_user"


class AppUser(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    group = ForeignKey('Group', null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    zip = CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "app_users"


class Group(Model):                
    creator = ForeignKey(AppUser, related_name='+')
    created = DateTimeField()
    name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "groups"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to always start from the model you actually want to fetch. In this case, you want to fetch emails, which is a field on the User model. So, start with that model, and use the double-underscore syntax to follow the relationships to Group:

```
users = User.objects.filter(appuser__group_id=group_id)
```

In this case, you actually only need a single JOIN, because `group_id` is a field on AppUser itself (it's the underlying db field for the `group` ForeignKey). If you had the group name, you would need two joins:

```
users = User.objects.filter(appuser__group__name=group_name)
```

Comment: You can also follow fks when adding a `values` or `values_list` clause to a query, eg `group.appuser_set.values('user__email')`.

Comment: That. Is. Cool. The underscore syntax seems bizarre at first but I can see the utility of it once you're used to it. I had to change the method from all() to filter() but other than that it worked like a champ. Thanks!